# Ordering return of Child objects in JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So if my JPA query is like this:
Select distinct p from Parent p left join fetch p.children order by p.someProperty

I correctly get results back ordered by p.someProperty, and I correctly get my p.children collection eagerly fetched and populated.  But I'd like to have my query be something like "order by p.someProperty, p.children.someChildProperty" so that the collection populated inside each parent object was sub-ordered by someChildProperty.

This seems intuitive when I think in terms of the sql that is actually generated for these calls, but I guess less so when it tries to map back to hierarchical objects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For preserving order, use [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). As far as, sorting of a collection inside parent is concerned, just do it in your code using [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Well, try this on your collection definition in your parent entity class. I hope you are getting my point.

You can use this JPA annotation,

```
@javax.persistence.OrderBy(value = "fieldName")
```

or this Hibernate specific,

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy(clause = "FIELD_NAME asc")
```

and you can also use this,

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
```

or

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR)
```

In the case of comparator, a comparator must be in place. Other might only work with String collections.

Comment: as a generic alternative you can use the javax annotation: @javax.persistence.OrderBy(value = "fieldName")

Comment: I tried @javax.persistence.OrderBy(value = "fieldName") where fieldName is an integer. It fetches child collection in descending order and when I use @javax.persistence.OrderBy("fieldName") then it fetches the child collection in ascending order. It is quite strange to me, As per the documentation ASC and DESC should be appended with field name but it is not impacting the results.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using springboot and jpa here's the example

in parent class add the code like below

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@OrderBy(value = "position desc ")
private List<UserAddresses> userAddresses;
```

in the above code, position is the field name in **UserAddresses** Class and **desc** is the order. You can pass either **asc** or **desc** like in sql order by.

Comment: I used List which returns duplicate values. How do I make sure of uniqueness?

Comment: Instead of List can you try with Set ?

Answer (score 1):

Adeel basically has this nailed. You can also use those with a List which might be important if your collections contain the same entity more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` you can implement this when calling methods in your repository class that extends `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`.

For example, assuming the `Teacher` entity is a child of `School` and the `Student` entity is a child of `Teacher`

```
teacherRepository.findAll(Sort.by("school.name", "student.lastName"))
```

will sort results by the parent entity's `name` attribute, then by the child entity's `lastName` attribute.

NOTE: Adding the child attribute to the sort will of course force a join to the child table in the generated query. In this case, if you have more than one `Student` entity with the same `lastName` attribute the number of records returned to be greater unless you explicitly ask for distinct records.